# Location.pathname.indexOf not working with 'Or' ( || )

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I'm trying to use `location.pathname.indexOf` to make conditional jQuery work on some pages on my site.

This works:

```
if (location.pathname.indexOf("/example/5820.htm") != 0){}
```

This works:

```
if (location.pathname.indexOf("/example-1/3569.htm") != 0) {}
```

This doesn't work:

```
if (location.pathname.indexOf("/example/5820.htm") != 0 || location.pathname.indexOf("/example-1/3569.htm") != 0) {}
```

I've done this a ton of times and for some reason this code is not working. I'm wondering if I'm missing something little in the code or if it's something else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

basically you're saying this:

```
var a = 0;
var b = 1;
if (a != 0 || b != 0) {};
```

Which is equal to

```
if (!(a == 0 && b == 0)) {};
```

However, you actually want this:

```
if (!(a == 0 || b == 0)) {};
```

Which is equal to:

```
if (a != 0 && b != 0) {};
```

Comment: Ah, of course. My logic is off. I know that was basic, thanks for the quick answer. I'll accept in 10 minutes when it allows me. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Tim already answered this question, but don't forget:

.indexOf() will return -1 when the string isn't found, not 0.

```
if (location.pathname.indexOf("/example/5820.htm") != 0){}
```

Should be:

```
if (location.pathname.indexOf("/example/5820.htm") != -1){}
```

Or:

```
if (location.pathname.indexOf("/example/5820.htm") >= 0){}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp